# PHPEXCEL: Read a Spreadsheet->Audit and apply formats->Save audited Spreadsheet. MEMORY Problems

Tags: php, phpexcel

Much has been documented regarding PHPEXCEL memory issues so my question presumes that reading in "chunks" - as described by Mark Baker has been applied.  My specific situation is this:
- read a "raw" spreadsheet uploaded to a database record (working fine)
- retrieve said spreadsheet, open with PHPExcel, and audit the cells
- Read rows and columns and look for conditions.
- If a cell has a [informational|warning|error] (a) apply conditional formatting and insert a cell note (working fine)
- Do this for all rows and columns.  Runs out of memory before completes.
- Save the formatted spreadsheet into a server directory so user can download and look at all the embedded errors warnings, or informational items - also works just fine if I limit the number of rows read.

The spreadsheet is not especially big 130 or rows and 60 columns.

This is what I have tried:
- Reading in "chunks" ala Mark Baker.  Problem is the filter only returns the subset of rows.  Those associated with the chunk rule. So when I go to do a save at the end of a chunk read and processing, only those rows are saved, not the whole spreadsheet.
- Using cell caching (

```
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory::cache_to_discISAM;
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod);
```

) allows me to read and update every row and the associated cells, but when I go to do the `$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', $theDIRandFileName)` I get a memory problem in XMLWriter.php:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 18874368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 238592 bytes) in ... /PHPExcel/Shared/XMLWriter.php on line 100
```

Argh!

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Right now it appears the only thing left for me to try is open two copies, use the chunk approach, but figure out how to read the unedited version but update a chunk version.  There has to be a better way.

Comment: Simple questions: did You tried to set more memory in php.ini (18 Mib is really not enough for PHP)? Are You using a `for` or a `foreach` loops (`foreach` loop consumes much more memory and need more time to process the data)? Did You try to loop over the spreadsheet iterating over 50 rows at once and then saving and continue with next 50 rows while still removing the old rows from memory (not using chunks, just simply one `for` loop within another one)?